# Find a dynamic control in a dynamic HTML table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get find a dynamic control inside of a dynamic HTML table.  I have the following:

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow TR = null;
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell TD1 = null;
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell TD2 = null;
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell TD3 = null;
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell TD4 = null;
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell TD5 = null;
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell TD6 = null;

// Database stuff
int i = 1;
while (objRdr.Read())
{
    TR = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow();
    TD1 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell();
    TD2 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell();
    TD3 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell();
    TD4 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell();
    TD5 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell();
    TD6 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell();

    // ASP code maybe wrong, but its to give you the ID.
    TD1.InnerHtml = "<asp:RadioButton runat='server' ID='radApprove"+i.ToString()+"' Value='Approve' />";
    TD2.InnerText = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(objRdr[1].ToString());
    TD3.InnerText = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(objRdr[6].ToString());
    TD4.InnerText = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(objRdr[2].ToString());
    TD5.InnerText = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(objRdr[10].ToString());
    TD6.InnerText = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(objRdr[8].ToString());

    TR.Cells.Add(TD1);
    TR.Cells.Add(TD2);
    TR.Cells.Add(TD3);
    TR.Cells.Add(TD4);
    TR.Cells.Add(TD5);
    TR.Cells.Add(TD6);

    tblOrderItems.Rows.Add(TR);
    TR = null;
    TD1 = null;
    TD2 = null;
    TD3 = null;
    TD4 = null;
    TD5 = null;
    TD6 = null;
    i++;
}
```

Now, when I try to get the data out of the Cells, it fails.  I have tried:

```
this.FindControl("radApprove1");
```

But this returns a `null`.  I've also tried to iterate the rows in the table, but it only indicates 1 row and that is the Header.  This code is called from the `Page_Load`, so I thought that I'd be able to get these controls.  When I view the HTML source of the Page after it's rendered, I can see that they have been rendered correctly.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mind to up what is rendered for radApprove ?

Comment: Do I mind to up??  Not with you :oS

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use a "friendly data binding" control, such as the repeater or datagrid? I've had my fights with the `Table` control myself, and it feels like I always loose :-/

Comment: Have no idea what i typed lol, I mean do you mind to post what is rendered.

Comment: When you say "what is rendered" are you asking for the output?

Comment: This might not be the cause of your problem, but [truly understanding viewstate](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx) is a nice article about some of the pitfalls of viewstate in asp.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TD1.InnerHtml = "<asp:RadioButton runat='server' ID='radApprove"+i.ToString()+"' Value='Approve' />"
```

Not completely sure if the above will work. Why don't you consider using an `<asp:Table>` for handling this problem?

There is a technique for finding child controls to a limited degree: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2006/08/25/Finding-ASP.NET-Child-Controls_2E002E002E002E00_The-Simple-Way.aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

this.FindControl("radApprove1"); only checks the main INamingContainer for your control.
You need to find it recursively or do:

Pseudo:

```
foreach row in a table.Rows
  foreach cell in row
    cell.FindControl()
```

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I have tried this and the table says it has 1 row which is the column headings.